# Connection to a remote MySQL Database via RODBC returning 0 rows

Tags: mysql, r, rodbc, rmysql

I am using Windows 10 64-bit.
I downloaded a MySQL 64-bit ODBC driver and set it up via Administrative Tools -> ODBC drivers. I put the IP address of the MySQL database, id and password and then clicked on "Test" which verified that the connection was working.
I ran the following code in R

```
library("RODBC")
ch <- odbcConnect("xyz")
sqlTables(ch)
```

This gives me a result

```
[1] TABLE_CAT   TABLE_SCHEM TABLE_NAME  TABLE_TYPE  REMARKS    
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

The DBA sent me a web-link (phpMyAdmin) where I log in using the same id and password. There, I can browse and see that there are 2 databases - x and y and I need to access a table z in the y database. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong or why sqlTables is returning 0 rows?

If I try running `sqlFetch(ch,"z")` it says :

```
Error in odbcTableExists(channel, sqtable) : 
  ‘z’: table not found on channel
```

If i browse through the phpMyAdmin link I can see that z exists...
I'm new to database management and R so any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer! 
When we have to setup ODBC connections in Windows, I needed to select the database in the Administrative Tools -> MySQL ODBC Connector option(alongwith the id and password).
So selecting database -> 'y' then allowed my SQLFetch to work.

I hope this helps anyone else who was stuck on a similar problem.